# Doubts regarding creating Magento Mobile App

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

We are planning to create a mobile app for our magento web application. However i'm bit confused on where to start from. We have decided to use the magento REST API Now my doubts are

1. Are there options to search the products and retrieve the results
   using REST    API. As per information on this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/configure-magento-rest-and-oauth-settings/) i can
   understand that it supports managing customers, customer addresses,
   sales orders, inventory, and products. There is no information about
   searching.   [1](http://inchoo.net/magento/configure-magento-rest-and-oauth-settings/):
   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html
2. How  to create the checkout process (Onepage checkout). Is there are an option in REST API to create the checkout process

I have followed the steps in this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/configure-magento-rest-and-oauth-settings/) but when i try to access the API like http://localhost/magento/api/rest/products its returing a 404 error. I have also tried http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/rest/products but it also returing 404 error.